# Можно ли подключить шеринг от Яндекса через класс

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Есть у меня постраничный слайдер, в каждом слайде отдельная статья. Для каждой статьи свой блок с шерингом. Можно ли повесить создание нового блока передав в кач-ве аргумента имя класса вместо `id`. Т.к. в ином случае придется создавать каждый раз новый `id` и обращаться к нему. Сейчас при обращении через имя класса у меня выдает ошибку:

```
this.initSocshare = function(el, services) {
    new Ya.share2(el, {
        content: {
            url: 'https://yandex.com',
            title: 'Yandex',
            theme: {
                services: services
            }
        }
    });
}
```

И соотв. вызываю:

```
initSocshare('.socshare_b-container', 'facebook,twitter,vkontakte,gplus');
```

Вот самам ошибка:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#.socshare_b-container' is not a valid selector.
```

Пробовал вызывать и с точкой и без.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, указать селектор класса в конструкторе нельзя.

Зато, как сказано в [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/api-docpage/), можно передать сам элемент.

```
const el = document.querySelector('.my-class');

Ya.share2(el, params);
```

Обратите внимание, что `new` при создании блока использовать не нужно.