# ссылки поделится не работает в single page для картинок

Tags: javascript, jquery, share

Есть одностраничный сайт, где работает js-слайдер картинок.
При нажатии на кнопку шаринга должен шарить страница с той картинкой, что в данный момент на слайдере, но к сожалению не работает.
при смене картинок на слайдере, я по очередности меняю данные

```
meta name="title" property="og:title"
meta name="desc" property="og:description"
meta name="img" property="og:image"
```

но все равно не шарит страницу с конкретной картинкой, думаю это из за того, что я их меняю javascript-ом и они уже не видны для скрипта шаринга.
Если кто столкнулся с такой проблемой подскажите пожалуйсто, что я делаю не так. 
За ранее спасибо.

Comment: https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/issues/749 - надо пробовать, у каждой соцсети свои тонкости, у каждого слайдера также.

Comment: мне надо как то динамично обновить данные, что бы скрипт share видел эти изменения.

Comment: что за скрипт? какая соцсеть? они все разные

Comment: скрипя - я про шаринга. соцсеть - facebook, vk,G+,

Comment: Yandex Share значит скрипт.

Comment: вот тут похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628604/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81

Answer (score 0):

Соц сети, не скажу про все, но facebook точно, кеширует данные для страницы, поэтому сколько не меняйте в js meta теги, результат не поменяется.
Возможно стоит к урл еще хештег добавлять, что бы это разными урлами было. Слайдер можно тоже заточить, что бы при наличии хештега сразу делать активным тот или иной пункт в слайдере.
Что-то типа mysite.ru#slide2

Comment: По поводу кеширования ты прав, а по поводу хэша - сервер не может его прочитать...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256114/how-to-clear-facebook-sharer-cache
Вот здесь есть ответ, кеш чистится вручную на каждой странице.

Comment: 1. какой сервер не может его прочитать и зачем его читать? 2. Почистить вручную можно, но автора это не устроит точно.

Comment: Есть уникальность урла, по которым идет индексирование с соц сетей и с поисковиков, запросы идут серверные: 
example.com/blog и 
example.com/blog#123 
будут читаться, как example.com/blog 
Если не веришь - попробуй на php, например, прочесть хеш. Это может сделать только js.

Comment: А если параметры ввести, например example.com?slider=123

Comment: Параметры - да, хеш - нет (имеется ввиду прочитать, про уникальность не знаю, честно). Я говорю именно про хеш, не пытаюсь спорить, просто недавно пытался получить токен с вк и столкнулся с подобной проблемой, что они возвращают хеш, который сервером не прочесть, поэтому и решил уточнить. Не принимай на свой счет - твоя идея хороша, просто нужно немного доработать :)

Comment: Договорились, плакать не буду )))